# AngularJS ngDisabled not working inside a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple form that registers the informations in a MailChimp's list. I want to disable the Submit button if the input fields weren't filled yet.

```
<div class="demo" data-ng-if="demo && !register">
                    <form action="MAILCHIMP_ADDRESS" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate demoform" data-ng-init="demoUser = {}" target="_blank" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="EMAIL" data-ng-model="demoUser.email" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail profissional">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="EMPRESA" data-ng-model="demoUser.empresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira sua empresa">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0a5d36c63e174c949789feea5_200f88e472" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                        <div class="clear pull-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-ng-disabled="mc-embedded-subscribe-form.$invalid" data-ng-click="demoLogin(demoUser)">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using a hyphen in the name of your form. 
Its a known issue explained [here](http://richguan.azurewebsites.net/the-hyphen-with-angular/) also stated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/DgQHXeNGLN0).
So you will have to change your form name to  `myForm`or something without a hyphen.

```
data-ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
```

check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GdyfJCuLTv9Z1vHZR4KQ?p=preview) the one form with the hyphen is not working, the other does

Comment: Forms with dashes in the name do not work. The other thing is that if you want the button to remain disabled you have to check if form was "touched" by the user and chec $pristine.

please see what outputs {{myForm}} in the view and see all the validator fields.

Comment: Still not working. Maybe the ngDisable have some conflict with something in the form?

Comment: Whoops! I forgot to mark the input fields as `required`. Now it works, I'll change the name form with no dashes. Thanks!